# Knockout Nested Foreach binding taking too much time

Tags: performance, knockout.js, foreach

Please check this binding as when I update the main observable array then binding is taking too much time: about 12 to 15 sec to bind .

When size is less then it is not taking too much time but when size is more than 200 then it takes time to bind html .

I have reduced my json too but still not much improvement.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover quot-tble mb0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="wd245px">Room category </th>
            <!-- ko if:this.CheckRedeem() != '0'-->

            <th class="wd50px">Points</th>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <th class="text-center wd145px">Board Basis</th>
            <th class="wd50px">Offer</th>
            <th class="text-center wd145px">Total for&nbsp;  <span id="lblnoofnights" data-bind="text: NoofNights() + ' '"></span>Nights</th>
            <th class="text-center wd145px">Policy</th>
            <th class="wd106px text-center">Book</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: RoomTypesDispNew()-->
        <!-- ko foreach:$data-->
        <tr class="" data-bind="attr: { 'data-roomname': RoomTypeName.toString().split('|***')[0] }">
            <td class="wd245px">
                <div class="roomcatagory">
                    <div class="pl8 rtype">
                        <span data-bind="text: RoomTypeName.toString().split('|***')[0]"></span>
                         <a style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" data-bind="click: function () { ShowEssentialsInfo(SupplierName, RoomNo, $index(), $parentContext.$index(), OwnsystemHotelId, RoomTypeId, '', ContractID, MealId, IsPolicyDynamic) }, attr: { class: 'soap-popupbox ' + (EssentialInformation == null || EssentialInformation == '' || SupplierName.toLowerCase() == 'trvaco' ? 'hide' : '') }" title="Essential Information"
                                href="#info">
                                <span class="info_icon list_details_srip"></span>
                            </a>
            <!-- ko if:hdnIsShowSupplierFilter == '1'-->

                        <br /> <span class='hotel_type'  data-bind="text: RoomTypeName.toString().split('|***')[1]=='oth' ? 'Withinearth' : RoomTypeName.toString().split('|***')[1]"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->

                    </div>
                   <%-- <div class="avlableinfo quotH">
                        <span>

                        </span>
                    </div>--%>

                </div>
                 <div class="tbl-cell" data-bind="foreach: $root.OriginalNoofRooms">
                        <div class="text-center" data-bind="if: $index() > 0 && $parent.IsCombineRoom">+</div>

                        <div class="" data-bind="if: $parent.IsCombineRoom ? (true) : ($parent.RoomNo == RoomNo),attr: { class: $index() > 0 ? 'ad-ch-div' : 'ad-ch-div' }" >
                            <span style="" data-bind="foreach: new Array(parseInt(NoofAdults))">
                                <i class="fa fa-user " style=""></i>
                            </span>
                            <span style="" data-bind="foreach: new Array(parseInt(NoofChild))">
                                <i class="fa fa-user font-10"></i>
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="font-12 text-black" data-bind="text: 'Room ' + RoomNo "></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <br>
            </td>
            <!-- ko if:($index()==0 || (IsCombineRoom))&& this.CheckRedeem() != '0'-->

            <td class="wd50px text-center" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: IsCombineRoom ? 1 : RowSpan }">
                <span data-bind="attr: { class: TotalPoints == null || parseInt(TotalPoints) == 0 || this.CheckRedeem() == '0' ? 'hide' : 'point_gold_silver ' + LoyaltyPointsIcon + '_Points' }"><span class="point_text" data-bind="    text: TotalPoints">999</span><span class="points_tooltrip"><span class="point_tool_text"></span></span></span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if:$index()==0 || (IsCombineRoom)-->

            <td class="text-left wd145px" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: IsCombineRoom ? 1 : RowSpan }">
                <span data-bind="attr: { class: MealClass + ' list_details_srip' }" class=""></span>
                <span class="font-13 ver_base" data-bind="text: MealName"></span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <td class="wd50px text-center">

                <span data-bind="if: OfferDescription.length > 0"><i class="fa fa-tags" title="kLPWBJS" data-bind="    attr: { title: OfferCode + ' ' + OfferDescription }" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

            </td>
            <!-- ko if:$index()==0 || (IsCombineRoom)-->

            <td class="text-center wd145px" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: IsCombineRoom ? 1 : RowSpan }">
                <div class="" data-bind="attr: { class: (WithOutDiscount == null || WithOutDiscount == '' || WithOutDiscount == '0' || (parseInt(RoomPrice) == parseInt(WithOutDiscount)) ? ' hide line_ht hide' : '  line_ht') }">
                    <span class="priceline"><span class=" blue_pricecol currencysymbol red_txt" data-bind="html: this.CurrencySymbol()"></span><span class="blue_pricecol currencytext red_txt" data-bind="    text: CalculatePrice(WithOutDiscount)"></span></span>
                    <br>
                    <a class="soap-popupbox hotel_type" title="Rate breakup"
                        href="#breakup" data-bind="click: function () { ShowRateBreakup(IsCombineRoom, IsPolicyDynamic, IsCombineRoom ? $index() : 0, RoomTypesDispNew()[$parentContext.$index()]) }, attr: { href: '#Rate-breakup-popup-new' }">
                        <span class=""><span class="currencysymbol" data-bind="html: this.CurrencySymbol()"></span><span class="currencytext" data-bind="    text: CalculatePrice(RoomPrice)"></span></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="" data-bind="attr: { class: (WithOutDiscount == null || WithOutDiscount == '' || WithOutDiscount == '0' || (parseInt(RoomPrice) == parseInt(WithOutDiscount)) ? '' : ' hide') }">
                    <a class="soap-popupbox hotel_type" title="Rate breakup"
                        href="#breakup" data-bind="click: function () { ShowRateBreakup(IsCombineRoom, IsPolicyDynamic, IsCombineRoom ? $index() : 0, RoomTypesDispNew()[$parentContext.$index()]) }, attr: { href: '#Rate-breakup-popup-new' }">
                        <span class="currencysymbol" data-bind="html: this.CurrencySymbol()">AED</span> <span
                            class="currencytext" data-bind="text: CalculatePrice(RoomPrice)"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <td class="policy-icon text-center wd145px">
                <a href="#cancellation" class="soap-popupbox display_inline" data-bind="click: function () { ShowCancelationPolicy($data, $parents[1].XMLCode, $parents[1].ContractName, $parents[1].OfficeID, $parents[1].XMLHotelCode, IsPolicyDynamic, IsCombineRoom) }">


                    <!-- ko if: cancellationText=='' -->
                    <span class="policy_icon list_details_srip" data-bind="attr: { id: 'policyicon' + $parentContext.$index() + $index() }"></span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: cancellationText!='' -->
                    <!-- ko if: cancellationText.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('within') >= 0 -->
                    <i class="fa fa-usd doller-icon" data-bind="attr: { id: 'policyicon' + $parentContext.$index() + $index() }"></i>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: cancellationText.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('free') >= 0 -->
                    <i class="fa fa-check green-color" data-bind="attr: { id: 'policyicon' + $parentContext.$index() + $index() }"></i>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <span data-bind="text: cancellationText, attr: { id: 'policytext' + $parentContext.$index() + $index(), class: (cancellationText.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('within') >= 0 ? 'line_div text-red' : 'line_div green-color ') }"></span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'policy' + $parentContext.$index() + $index() }"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <!-- ko if:$index()==0 || (IsCombineRoom)-->

            <td class="text-center wd106px hotellist" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: IsCombineRoom ? 1 : RowSpan }">
                <a data-bind="click: function () { BookNow(IsCombineRoom, IsCombineRoom ? $index() : 0, RoomTypesDispNew()[$parentContext.$index()], $parents[1].XMLHotelCode, $parents[1].OfficeID, $parents[1].ContractName) }, text: IsSelected ? 'Added' : BookingStatus.replace(' ', '') == 'OnRequest' ? 'Book On Request' : BookingStatus.replace(' ', '') == 'PackageRate' ? 'Book PackageRate' : 'Book Available', attr: { style: BookingStatus.replace(' ', '') == 'OnRequest' ? 'background:#ff5d00!important;' : '', title: RowSpan + ' Units', class: 'pull-right full-width button btn-small btn_booknow text-center back_blue_btn textcap' }">Book Available
                </a>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you show your js code as well? We can't say for sure the problem is in the html

Comment: Thnx ray for quick action  , when i assign value to my obserable array then browser hang for too much time as length of array is about >500

Comment: You have a huge html template AND your observablearray length is more than 500... Then the right strategy is to use pagination, with an array that holds only some data at a time, while the array with 500 items is not bound to the HTML.
Here's an example https://codepen.io/allicarn/pen/flmjx

Comment: It's not a recommended UX design anyway to show the user 500+ items at once.

Comment: thnx Ray but is there any way to achive this as in my case array  may be >2000 too as per requirement i have to do this , so is any way to achive plz let me know

Comment: As far as I know, there's not much you can do, apart from notifying subscribers to re-render the HTML only after all items are added to the observablearray. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html
Maybe other people can suggest something more.

Comment: Okk thx so much for your help